# Balloon tips google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

This problem has come again in the latest version of chrome 91.0.4472.124 64 bit:

[image]

All the sudden I am experiencing balloon tooltips. I wanted to get rid of them with chrome://flags:

[image]

But it doesn't help at all. Any idea how to get rid of annoying balloon tips?

Answer (score 1):

After disabling those options in chrome://flags, did you relaunch Chrome?
If you did and they still appear try reinstalling the browser. Hope that helps.

Comment: you don't need to reinstall, chrome has the option to reset

Comment: I have reinstalled chrome. It didn't help.